# Wiremock : Match String Request

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-test, wiremock, stubbing

I am having trouble matching following string request using wiremock stub.I am not able find any examples where the request is of type string.Below is my following string request which was build to call graphql query.

Request:

```
{
  graphQLRequest(
    firstName: "JOHN",
    lastName: "DOE",
  ) {
    email
    fullname
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Graphql is a simple `POST` request to a specific URL, so essentially you have to match the body with your request sample. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you add your current WireMock JSON rule, or Java code, and what you observe it does?

Comment: @Rocky4Ever, did you find a way for request matching for graphql query?

Comment: So I ended up Creating request as string and pass